# Svelte Derived store error : "Cannot find name '$t'."

Tags: svelte, store

I have a derived store :

```js
export const t = derived(locale, ($locale) => (key, vars = {}) =>
  translate($locale, key, vars)
);
```

I have used it by importing the function in lots of .svelte files and using it this way without problems :

```js
$t("account.login")
```

it returns a string that is then used as a variable.

But in my .ts files, I import the file correctly with the function and I get a "Cannot find name '$t'.ts(2304)".
I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use [`$`-notation](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-4-prefix-stores-with-$-to-access-their-values) in anything except Svelte files.

You have to interact with the store using `.subscribe` or use the [`get` utility function](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-get) to retrieve the value once. When using subscribe you may also have to unsubscribe to prevent leaks.

---

What the `$` does:

> Any time you have a reference to a store, you can access its value inside a component by prefixing it with the `$` character. This causes Svelte to declare the prefixed variable, subscribe to the store at component initialization and unsubscribe when appropriate.