# Error In Method From svelte-i18n When Included in Imported File

Tags: typescript, svelte

I am working on Svelte 3.53.1 site. I have a page that includes a .TS file that imports svelte-i18n (version 3.6.0) like:

```
import { number } from "svelte-i18n";

alert($number(100000000, { locale: "en" }));
```

However, on page load I get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $number is not defined

If I include that same snippet on the "main" page that I am including our .TS file on it works as expected.

I want to have the necessary localized number formatting in the .TS file so I can re-use on other pages.

In my main file I have these imports:

```
import Layout from "./shared/layout/main.svelte";
import urls from "./shared/urls";
import { onMount, tick, onDestroy } from "svelte";
import { get, getCookie } from "./shared/config";
import jQuery from "jquery";
import Select from 'svelte-select';
import { CompanyResultTable } from "./search/CompanySearchResultTable";
import { toast } from '@zerodevx/svelte-toast';
```

I have even tried importing the svelte-i18n in this main page only and issue persists in the imported TS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Svelte Derived store error : "Cannot find name '$t'."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76171433/svelte-derived-store-error-cannot-find-name-t)

Comment: @H.B. ahh, so I cannot use $ in non-svelte files. That makes sense. However, I cannot make heads or tales of the svelte-i18n documentation on how to implement another way.

Comment: Just use `get(number)(...)`.

Comment: Or create a `derived` store if ultimately it should be used in a component anyway. Depends on use case.